# How does one count duplicates within an array of data-items and also does display this result via a react view?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, data-structures, reduce

Lets say my array is

```
[{id: 1,
name: "chocolate bar"},
{id:2,
name: "Gummy worms"},
{id:3,
name:"chocolate bar"}]
```

How do I display on the dom "2 chocolate bars and 1 Gummy Worms"?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try so far, or how would you approach this task. Just share something more than just the plain question in order to let others solve your problem.

Comment: if there are no open questions you might consider accepting the answer which was most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
const array = [
   {
    id: 1,
    name: "chocolate bar"
   },
   {
    id:2,
    name: "Gummy worms"
   },
   { 
    id:3,
    name:"chocolate bar"
   }
];

 ...

const countCandy = candyName => array.filter(obj => obj.name === candyName).length

 ...

return (
   <div>{`${countCandy("chocolate bar")} chocolate bars and ${countCandy("Gummy worms")} Gummy Worms`}<div>
)
```

or a more generic approach will be to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and return object:

```
const countCandy = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.name] = (acc[cur.name] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {})

 ...

 return (
       <div>{Object.entries(countCandy).map((el) => `${el[1]} ${el[0]}`)}<div>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `reduce()` method and `Object.assign()` you can create a new object containing the counted duplicates.

Displaying it on the DOM can be done in many different ways. I added a example of creating a list item of it. You should be able to modify that to your likings.

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "chocolate bar"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Gummy worms"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "chocolate bar"
  }
]

//SUmmarize the source arr
const summary = arr.reduce((accumulator, item) => Object.assign(accumulator, {
  [item.name]: (accumulator[item.name] || 0) + 1
}), {});

//Example how to show it on the dom, modify to your likings
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(summary)) {
  document.querySelector('#target').innerHTML += `<li>${k}: ${v}</li>`
}
```

```html
<ul id="target"></ul>
```

Comment: @PeterSeliger Display it on the DOM is pretty broad. But added an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var temp = {};
  var array = [
    { id: 1, name: "chocolate bar" },
    { id: 2, name: "Gummy worms" },
    { id: 3, name: "chocolate bar" }
  ]; 

array.forEach(value => {
      if (!this.temp[value.name]) {
        this.temp[value.name] = 1;
      } else {
        this.temp[value.name]++;
      }
    });
```

And use temp variable in your display

Answer (score 0):

```js
const candyDataList = [
  { id: 1, name: "chocolate bar" },
  { id: 2, name: "Gummy worms" },
  { id: 3, name: "chocolate bar" },
];

function getNameDuplicateCounts (dataItemList) {
  return dataItemList.reduce((duplicateCounts, dataItem) => ({
  
    ...duplicateCounts,
    [dataItem.name]: (duplicateCounts[dataItem.name] || 0) + 1,

  }), {});
}
console.log(
  'getNameDuplicateCounts(candyDataList) :',
  getNameDuplicateCounts(candyDataList)
);

function NameItems(nameCounts) {
  return Object
    .entries(nameCounts)
    .map(([itemName, itemCount]) =>

      <li>{ itemName }: { itemCount }</li>
      // <dt>{ itemName }</dt>
      // <dd>{ itemCount }</dd>
    );
}
function CandyNameCounts() {
  const nameCounts = getNameDuplicateCounts(candyDataList);
  return (
    <ul>{ NameItems(nameCounts) }</ul>
    // <dl>{ NameItems(nameCounts) }</dl>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<CandyNameCounts/>, document.querySelector("#react-root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: @DavidWilliams ... are there any questions left?